# I installed ethereum miner and I wonder how to transfer from ballance

Tags: wallets, alethzero

I seem to have 40 ether in my wallet in Alethzero frontier. how do I transfer this to my ethereum wallet?

when I click transaction I can only submit contracts...

However , Are my Ether legitimate mined as they might be mined before I synced and properly installed my geth.
[image: AlethZero screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried to access your account directly using Geth command line ? Why do you want to do it with Aleth0 ?

Comment: The account with 40 ether is not in my geth wallet.

Comment: Are you sure it's ether mined on the main net ? How long did it take to mine and what graphic card do you use ?

Comment: That's what i'm afraid off, That its not mined on main net.  That is why i need to know how i validate it.

Comment: if you mined it on testnet you will never be able to use it on main net. They are isolated. Ether on the test net is just for testing purposes.